# GWT with multiple entry points in same module

Tags: gwt

Is there any priority to run the multiple entry points in a same module ?

Which one will execute here..

Comment: You may want to read this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929661/problem-with-multiple-entry-points-in-the-same-module?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

They'll just execute in the order they've been read by GWT (with inheriteded modules being read at the place of the `<inherit>` element)